# C++ Terminate Called 'std::length_error'?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, terminate

Here is the error I get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_S_create
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

I am reading a file that has about 50 lines. Do you see the issue in my code below?

```
using namespace std;

bool areParenthesesBalanced(const std::string& expr)
{
    stack<char> s;
    char a, b, c;

    for (int i=0; i<expr.length(); i++)
    {
        if (expr[i]=='(' || expr[i]=='[' || expr[i]=='{')
        {
            s.push (expr[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (expr[i])
            {
                case ')':
                a = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (a=='{' || a=='[')
                cout<<"Not Balanced";
                break;

                case '}':
                b = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (b=='(' || b=='[')
                cout<<"Not Balanced";
                break;

                case ']':
                c = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (c=='(' || c=='{')
                cout<<"Not Balanced";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (s.empty())  //check if stack is empty
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream t("prog1.cpp");
    std::string str;
    t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    str.reserve(t.tellg());
    t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    if(areParenthesesBalanced(str))
    {
        cout<<"Balanced";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not Balanced";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't get the `top` from the stack, or `pop` it, if the stack is empty. You need to add a check for that.

Comment: @TevinTwoTimes Don't for get to accept the answer, please. It solves your problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question:**

To do `std::string::assign`, the string needs to be `resize`d to be able to contain that range, not `reserve`d. `std::string::append` or `std::copy` with `std::back_inserter` would work, though.

---

**Something else:**

You are not checking whether the stack is empty before accessing/popping its top element.

And maybe you want to `return` something, instead of doing `cout<<"Not Balanced";` in `areParenthesesBalanced`.

---

Not errors:

<sup>You can make the loop contain only the `switch` statement.</sup>

<sup>I don't think you need any of `a`, `b` and `c` variables. You should `pop` after all comparisons with `std::stack::top`.</sup>

<sup>Lastly, please write `return s.empty();` instead of six more lines.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If the stack is empty it will throw error. Please put a condition before using that. Also a little correction to your code. This might work...

using namespace std;

```
    bool areParenthesesBalanced(const std::string& expr)
    {
        stack<char> s;
        char a, b, c;

        for (int i=0; i<expr.length(); i++)
        {
            if (expr[i]=='(' || expr[i]=='[' || expr[i]=='{')
            {
                s.push (expr[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                switch (expr[i])
                {
                    case ')':
                    a = s.top();
                    s.pop();
                    if (a=='{' || a=='[')
                    cout<<"Not Balanced";
                    break;

                    case '}':
                    b = s.top();
                    s.pop();
                    if (b=='(' || b=='[')
                    cout<<"Not Balanced";
                    break;

                    case ']':
                    c = s.top();
                    s.pop();
                    if (c=='(' || c=='{')
                    cout<<"Not Balanced";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (s.empty())  //check if stack is empty
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream t("prog1.cpp");
        std::string str;
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        str.resize(t.tellg());
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        if(areParenthesesBalanced(str))
        {
            cout<<"Balanced";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Not Balanced";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```